# Publishsing jax-ws webservice on multiple url's

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, jax-ws, websphere-7

How can I customize jax-ws webservice to be available on more than one url. I have a webserice named commonService. By default it is hosted at www.examples.com/commonservice?wsdl

I need to host it in multiple paths as below

www.examples.com/corporate/commonservices
www.example.com/retail/commonservices

I am using websphere 7 and Jdk1.6

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create multiple endpoints in your sun-jaxws.xml file? I would try using the same configuration in terms of implementation, interface, but a different URL pattern - not sure if that'll work though :)

Comment: I am not user Will the sun-jaws.xml work in websphere 7 ( I am not using metro). Adding an end point will i need to change my wsdl ? Any hints ?

Comment: Haven't tried metro + websphere, but seems someone did successfully: http://www.myeclipseide.com/PNphpBB2-viewtopic-t-21370.html

Comment: Yes I have earlier implemented metro. Later switched to container based jax-ws since I had issues when calling services out side my application. There is a PMR pending with IBM